# Waves Equation solution using Parallelogram law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this problem :

$$(1) \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }   U_{tt} -c^2U_{xx} =0$$ $0 < x < ∞, t > 0$
$$ (2)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }U(x,0)=f(x) $$
$$(3)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } U_{t}(x,0) = g(x) $$
$$(4)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }U(0,t)=0 $$
Let's say I'm looking for a solution at $$ U(A) $$ 
how can I use the Parallelogram law to solve this? ?

Comment: There are many techniques to solve such pde!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has the form, from the 3rd boundary condition,
$$
U(x,t)=h(ct+x)-h(ct-x).
$$
Then $f(x)=U(x,0)=h(x)-h(-x)$ and $g(x)=U_t(x,0)=ch'(x)-ch'(-x)$ which allows to solve for $h(x)$.